# Changing the size of a UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage

so I have this function:

```
- (UIImage*)imageByCombiningImage:(UIImage*)firstImage withImage:(UIImage*)secondImage {
    UIImage *image = nil;

    UIImageView *temp_img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400)];
    temp_img.image = secondImage;
    secondImage = temp_img.image;



    CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(MAX(firstImage.size.width, secondImage.size.width), MAX(firstImage.size.height, secondImage.size.height));
    if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImageSize); 
    }

    [firstImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-firstImage.size.width)/2), 
                                        roundf((newImageSize.height-firstImage.size.height)/2))]; 
    [secondImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((100)), 
                                         roundf((100)))]; 
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Im trying to change the size of the secondImage UIImage so that when they merge I can adjust the size to make it look good.

Any help is appreciated thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the "0" in UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, newSize.height);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);
...
// make anySize the size you want and pt any point

CGContextDrawImage(context, (CGRect){ pt1, anySize1 }, [first CGImage]);
// make anySize the size you want and pt any point
CGContextDrawImage(context, (CGRect){ pt2, anySize2 }, [secondImage CGImage]);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
```

Comment: I tried this but the image just appears upside down... Could you update your post with the full function? the second Image is flipped vertically... I tried some methods to flip it back but it didnt seem to work.

Comment: I forgot one line - adding it now:   CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);